# How to build a javascript function as an object in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to build an object in C# like this.

```
public JsonResult GetMyObject(){
var MyObject = 
    new 
    {
      Myfunction = "function (params) {
            var res = params[0].seriesName + ' ' + params[0].name;
            res += '<br/>  Start : ' + params[0].value[0] + '  Max : ' + params[0].value[3];
            res += '<br/>  End : ' + params[0].value[1] + '  Min : ' + params[0].value[2];
            return res;
        }",
      Element1 = "Test Element",
      Element2 = 123
    };
    return Json(MyObject);
}
```

But when I return the json object to javascript, the "Myfunction" element in  MyObject is just a string, not a javascript function.

How can I build a javascript function as an object in C#?

Comment: what is your use case that you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: You need to take that string and using jquery append it to some part of your view where you already have script tags. I would write the code for you but I am outside on my phone. But should be easy and I am sure you can figure it out.

Comment: In general it's easier (and safer) to pass a simple JSON object (pure data) from a C# API to JavaScript AJAX code and write any necessary client-side logic in JavaScript.

Comment: JSON can not contain functions **.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want return object, better you can create a class, populate and send class as return item, it will send you JSON format.

```
  public class MyFucntion
{
    public string SeriesName { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Max { get; set; }
    public string Min { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject {
    public MyFucntion myFun { get; set; }
    public string Element1 { get; set; }
    public string Element2 { get; set; }
}
public JsonResult GetMyObject()
    {
        var fun = new MyFucntion
        {
            SeriesName =params[0].name,
            Max = params[0].value[3],
            Min = params[0].value[2],
            Start =params[0].value[0],
            End = params[0].value[1]
        };
        var obj = new MyObject {
            myFun = fun,
            Element1 ="ElE",
            Element2 = "ELE2"
        };
        return JSON(obj);
    }
```

If you are using asp.net website you can use web Mehtod and you need to change the code.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static MyObject GetMyObject()
    {
        var fun = new MyFucntion
        {
            SeriesName =params[0].name,
            Max = params[0].value[3],
            Min = params[0].value[2],
            Start =params[0].value[0],
            End = params[0].value[1]
        };
        var obj = new MyObject {
            myFun = fun,
            Element1 ="ElE",
            Element2 = "ELE2"
        };
        return obj;
    }
```